# How To change Font size of element in dark mode in MUI React Framework?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**i am using makestyles method for CSS in MUI now i want some if else  condition for dark and light mode**

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

```
titleNew: {
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    marginBottom: '8px',
    fontSize:"14px"
    // if  mode is light then font size 14px if modeis dark then fontsize 18px
    
},

subtitleNew: {
    marginBottom: '25px',
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
},
```

}));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the mode inside of the `theme` object and use a ternary:

```
fontSize: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '14px' : '18px'
```

Check out the docs for more information on dark mode/theming and how to get the user's preference:

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#dark-mode-by-default